# Icons and tags on mvnrepository.com

Tags: maven, tags, icons, repository, pom.xml

It seems it is possible on [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/) to associate an icon and some tags to a project. Here, for instance, the page about JUnit, where the two elements are highlighted.

[image: tags & icon for JUnit]

Do you know how to add this info to the project published in the repo ? Maybe something to the project `pom.xml` file should be added ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to put a logo tag directly under the project and organization tag with the URL of your logo in your pom.xml file. For more info you can check the Maven doc here: http://maven.apache.org/archives/maven-1.x/reference/maven-model/3.0.2/maven.html

**EDIT**

This was true for Maven 1.x. As far as I know, Maven 2.x takes the logo from your SCM. For instance, this is one of my projects on GitHub which is also on Maven with the same logo without me putting anything on the POM:

Github: https://github.com/BotMill

Maven: http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=botmill&ref=opensearch

Comment: Maven Central only seems to pull the logo when an artifact is first added. If you update the logo in GitHub, the Maven Central logo will not change.

Comment: My project is listed with an Octocat image, like any other with an `io.github.` group prefix. It ignored my github user image, which predates the project by years. So the logic seems fuzzy.

Comment: @LukeHutchison why this way not work for me? is there any other ways? my artifact url: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.iofairy/functional

Comment: @Guo as far as I remember, I had to file a ticket with Maven Central to get it fixed. But it was a long time ago, I don't really remember!

Comment: @Guo how do you push artifacts to Maven Central (eg. is it Sonatype)? Try filing a ticket with their open source product team, if it's Sonatype then they usually respond within a day or so.

Comment: @LukeHutchison Someone has already  asked a question about this. https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-52907 , https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-63612 , but  it's not their business.

Comment: You're right -- and I looked at my artifact on mvnrepository.com, and it doesn't even have the project logo. I thought I solved this years ago (and couldn't remember how), but it turns out I didn't ever solve it!