# How to add/update logo, tags and categories in mvnrepository artifacts

Tags: maven, mvn-repo

I can see logo(image), tags and categories in mvnrepository.

example: [google.guava](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/31.1-jre) is having as per
[screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLWO8.png)

Is there a way to do this in pom.xml? or any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661826/icons-and-tags-on-mvnrepository-com

Comment: So there's no way?

Comment: Have you read the answer?

Comment: yes, as per the answer in earlier version of maven 1.x it can be done by pom.xml but in maven 2.x takes the logo from your SCM. 
But its not working