# How to add icon to artifact in mvnrepository?

Tags: maven, maven-3, documentation, artifacts, mvn-repo

A lot of dependencies on the MvnRepository website https://mvnrepository.com/ display an icon. How can one integrate an icon?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Icons and tags on mvnrepository.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661826/icons-and-tags-on-mvnrepository-com)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, yes, but there is no working answer to my question

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I tried uploading an image to SCM, and also tried using the site maven plugin to create a file descriptor and add an icon there.